# Why doesn't Add-Migration generate a DbMigration automatically?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

When ever I add a new Model, few days back on executing **Add-Migration ModelName** 
The DbMigration was getting generating automatically, all the basic create table thins were generating automatically. I only had to run **Update-Database** .

But few days back, whenever I add a new model, now on executing **Add-Migration ModelName** nothing happens it just generates the empty DbMigration like below :

```
 public partial class Blogs : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
```

There should be **create table** thing generated inside the Up() method and similarly rollback statement in Down(),

Anyone else has faced the same issue, can someone suggest what may be the cause ?

Thanks :)

Comment: did you actually add a `DbSet<T>` for the model class to your context?

Comment: No, but for the model auto generated, they also didnt had this. But will try after adding it :)

Comment: You're confusing `DbContext` and `DbMigration`.

Comment: there must be a `DbSet<T>` present for each class which will be mapped to a SQL table.  A "model" class is just a plain class. The `DbSet` is the wrapper that tells Entity Framework that you want a corresponding table for that class.

Comment: @GertArnold No, actually Not, I corrected the english.. :)